# How can I reverse the words in a sentence without using built-in functions?

Tags: c++, arrays, reverse, sentence

This was the interview question:

> How to convert **`Dogs like cats`** to **`cats like Dogs`** ?

My code shows: **`cats like cats`**. Where am I making the mistakes?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char sentence[] = ("dogs like cats");
    cout << sentence << endl;

    int len = 0;

    for (int i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        len++;
    }
    cout << len << endl;

    char reverse[len];
    int k = 0;

    for (int j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        reverse[k] = sentence[j];
        k++;
    }

    cout << reverse << endl;

    int words = 0;
    char str[len];

    for (int l = 0; reverse[l] != '\0'; l++)
    {
        if (reverse[l] == ' ' || reverse[l] == '\0') // not sure about this part
        {
            for (int m = l; m >= 0; m--)
            {
                str[words] = reverse[m];
                words++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << str;

    return 0;
}
```

I know you can do this using pointers, stack, vectors... but interviewer was not interested in that!

Comment: 1) reverse each word in place. 2) reverse the entire string.  Your code looks pretty complicated.

Comment: I don't know... I think your result is more accurate.

Comment: Write your version of `strrev` (left as an exercise for the reader). Use it to reverse the whole sentence. Then go hunting for spaces, and strrev individual words.

Comment: Sounds like a terrible c++ interview question, I'd be more concerned that c++ programmers understood how the standard library can make operations like this utterly trivial instead of faffing around with raw arrays.

Comment: `m` is counting down to 0 for each word. If I understand things correctly, you meant it to be counted down to the end of the previous word only.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments! that helps a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This is a fixed version of your sample code:

- Your principal problem is that every time you found and `' '` or `'\0'` you copy the bytes of the reverse string from the beginning to that point. Example in `loop 5` you copy from index 0-5 (`stac`) from `reverse` to `str` in reverse order, but in in `loop 10` you copy from index 0-10 (`stac ekil`) from `reverse` to `str` in reverse order, until here you have already the printed result string ('cats like cats'), and the same in `loop 15` all of this incrementing the index of `str`, in the last loop you are written pass the end of the valid memory of `str` (and because of that not printed as output).
- You need to keep track when end the last word reversed to reverse only the actual word, and not the string from the beginning to the actual index.
- You don't want to count the special character (' ' and '\0') in the reversing of the words, you would end with `cats like\0dogs`

Modified sample code provided:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char sentence[] = ("dogs like cats");
    cout << sentence << endl;

    int len = 0;

    for (int i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        len++;
    }
    cout << len << endl;

    char reverse[len];
    int k = 0;

    for (int j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        reverse[k] = sentence[j];
        k++;
    }

    cout << reverse << endl;

    int words = 0;
    char str[len];

    // change here added last_l to track the end of the last word reversed, moved
    // the check of the end condition to the end of loop body for handling the \0
    // case
    for (int l = 0, last_l = 0; ; l++) {
        if (reverse[l] == ' ' || reverse[l] == '\0')
        {
            for (int m = l - 1; m >= last_l; m--) { // change here, using last_t to
                str[words] = reverse[m];            // only reverse the last word
                words++;                            // without the split character
            }
            last_l = l + 1;                         // update the end of the last
                                                    // word reversed
            str[words] = reverse[l];                // copy the split character
            words++;
        }
        if (reverse[l] == '\0')                     // break the loop
            break;
    }

    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Some code, written with the restriction of using the most simple features of the language.

```
#include <iostream>

// reverse any block of text.
void reverse(char* left, char* right) {
    while (left < right) {
        char tmp = *left;
        *left = *right;
        *right = tmp;

        left++;
        right--;
    }
}

int main() {
    char sentence[] = "dogs like cats";
    std::cout << sentence << std::endl;

    // The same length calculation as sample code.
    int len = 0;
    for (int i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        len++;
    }
    std::cout << len << std::endl;

    // reverse all the text (ex: 'stac ekil sgod')
    reverse(sentence, sentence + len - 1);

    // reverse word by word.
    char* end = sentence;
    char* begin = sentence;
    while (end < sentence + len) {
        if (*end != ' ')
            end++;

        if (end == sentence + len || *end == ' ') {
            reverse(begin, end - 1);
            begin = end + 1;
            end = begin;
        }
    }

    std::cout << sentence << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dissecting your algorithm in pieces. First, you find the length of the string, not including the null char terminator. This is correct, though could be simplified.

```
size_t len = 0;
for (int i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    len++;
}
cout << len << endl;
```

This could easily be written simply as:

```
size_t len = 0;
while (sentence[len])
    ++len;
```

---

Next, you reverse the entire string, but the first defect surfaces. The VLA (variable length array) you declare here, (which you don't need and shouldn't use, as it is a C++ extension and non-standard) does not account for, nor set, a terminating null-char.

```
char reverse[len]; // !! should be len+1
int k = 0;
for (int j = len - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    reverse[k] = sentence[j];
    k++;
}
// !! Should have reverse[k] = 0; here.
cout << reverse << endl; // !! Undefined-behavior. no terminator.
```

This temporary buffer string is *not needed at all*. There is no reason you can't do this entire operation in-place. Once we calculate `len` correctly, you simply do something like the following to reverse the entire sequence, which retains the null char terminator in proper position:

```
// reverse entire sequence
int i = 0, j = len;
while (i < j--)
{
    char c = sentence[i];
    sentence[i++] = sentence[j];
    sentence[j] = c;
}
```

---

Next we move to where you try to reverse each internal word. Again, just as before, the buffer length is not correct. It should be `len+1`. Worse (hard to imagine), you never remember where you *left off* when finding the end point of a word. That location should be the *next* point you start checking for, and skipping, whitespace. Without retaining that you copy from current point all the way back to the beginning of the string. which essentially blasts `cats` over `dogs`.

```
int words = 0;
char str[len]; // !! should be len+1
for (int l = 0; reverse[l] != '\0'; l++) 
{
    if (reverse[l] == ' ' || reverse[l] == '\0') // not sure about this part
    {
        for (int m = l; m >= 0; m--) {
            str[words] = reverse[m];
            words++;
        }
    }
}
cout << str; //!! Undefined behavior. non-terminated string.
```

Once again, this can be done in-place without difficulty at all. One such algorithm looks like this (and notice the loop that reverses the actual word is not-coincidentally the same algorithm as reversing our entire buffer):

```
// walk again, reversing each word.
i = 0;
while (sentence[i])
{
    // skip ws; root 'i' at beginning of word
    while (sentence[i] == ' ') // or use std::isspace(sentence[i])
        ++i;

    // skip until ws or eos; root 'j' at one-past end of word
    j = i;
    while (sentence[j] && sentence[j] != ' ') // or use !std::isspace(sentence[j])
        ++j;

    // remember the last position
    size_t last = j;

    // same reversal algorithm we had before
    while (i < j--)
    {
        char c = sentence[i];
        sentence[i++] = sentence[j];
        sentence[j] = c;
    }

    // start at the termination point where we last stopped
    i = last;
}
```

---

**Putting It All Together**

Though considerably simpler to use pointers than all these index variables, the following will do what you're attempting, in place.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char s[] = "dogs like cats";
    std::cout << s << '\n';

    size_t len = 0, i, j;
    while (s[len])
        ++len;

    // reverse entire sequence
    i = 0, j = len;
    while (i < j--)
    {
        char c = s[i]; // or use std::swap
        s[i++] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }

    // walk again, reversing each word.
    i = 0;
    while (s[i])
    {
        // skip ws; root 'i' at beginning of word
        while (s[i] == ' ') // or use std::isspace
            ++i;

        // skip until ws or eos; root 'j' at one-past end of word
        j = i;
        while (s[j] && s[j] != ' ') // or use !std::isspace
            ++j;

        // remember the last position
        size_t last = j;
        while (i < j--)
        {
            char c = s[i]; // or use std::swap
            s[i++] = s[j];
            s[j] = c;
        }

        // start at last-left posiion
        i = last;
    }

    std::cout << s << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
dogs like cats
cats like dogs
```

Answer (score 0):

My advise would be to break up the original string into an array of words, reverse that array. Then add those words to your reversed sentence with a space in between.

Comment: or an array of pointers to each word, then reversing the array. You'd have to use spaces as terminators for each word (or replace the spaces with null characters ('\0').

Comment: Yes but the problem statement specifically says he can't use pointers.

Comment: So using indices is ok, but not pointers? Indices could be used in the same manner, an array of indices to the start of each word, but I don't see a significant difference.

Answer (score 0):

Since they asked for no libraries, I assumed no `std::string`, no `vectors`, nothing at all and so I wrote it in C.. the only thing used is `printf`. Everything else is from scratch :l

The idea is that you reverse the array first. Then split the array by space and reverse each word.

Example: http://ideone.com/io6Bh9

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strlen(const char* s)
{
    int l = 0;
    while (*s++) ++l;
    return l;
}


void reverse(char* str)
{
    int i = 0, j = strlen(str) - 1;

    for(; i < j; ++i, --j)
    {
       str[i] ^= str[j];
       str[j] ^= str[i];
       str[i] ^= str[j];
    }
}

void nulltok(char* str, char tok, int* parts)
{
    int i = 0, len = strlen(str);
    *parts = 1;

    for (; i < len; ++i)
    {
        if (str[i] == tok)
        {
            str[i] = '\0';
            ++(*parts);
        }
    }
}

char* reverse_sentence(char* str)
{
    char* tmp = str;
    reverse(str);

    int i = 0, parts = 0, len = strlen(str);
    nulltok(str, 0x20, &parts);

    while(parts--)
    {
        reverse(str);
        str += strlen(str) + 1;
    }

    for(; i < len; ++i)
        if (tmp[i] == '\0')
            tmp[i] = 0x20;

    return tmp;
}


int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "dogs like cats";
    printf("%s", reverse_sentence(str));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string str;
cout<<"enter the sentence"<<endl;
getline(cin,str);
char* pch;
pch = strtok((char*)str.c_str()," ");
string rev = "";

while(NULL != pch)
{
    rev.insert(0,pch);
    rev.insert(0," ");
    pch = strtok(NULL," ");
}
cout<<"the reversed string is :"<<rev<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

My Solution

```
string ReverseString(string S1) {
string ReversedString;

for (short i = S1.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if (S1[i] == ' ') {
        if (i == (S1.length() - 1)) {
            ReversedString += S1.substr(i);
            S1.erase(i);
        }
        else
        {
            ReversedString += S1.substr(i + 1);
            S1.erase(i + 1);
            /* 
            When space is between two words its iteration does not count,
            so it will not be saved in ReversedString,
            but will be shifted to the next word being part of it,
            so we increase the counter again after svaing the word to the ReversedStrin.
            */
            i++;
        }
        
    }
}
if (S1 != "")
{
    ReversedString += S1;
}

return ReversedString;
```

}

Comment: Is this "without using built-in functions", like the question requested?

Comment: @BoP You can easily create your own [length(), erase(), substr()] "without using built-in functions" and maybe you know that; I just jumped to the important part.