# How do I do reverse sentence in this simple way?

Tags: c

I have a problem with this code which is supposed to make a reverse sentence.

Example:

Input

```
Hi my name is Robert
```

Output

```
Robert is name my Hi
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 50

int main(void)
{
char input, terminator = 0, sentence[LEN+1] = {0};
int i, j, last_space = LEN + 1, posc=0;;
int pos[]={0};

printf("\nEnter a sentence: ");
for (i = 0; (input = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
{
    if(input== ' '){
        pos[posc]=i;
        posc++;
    }
    if (input == '.' || input == '?' || input == '!')
    {
        last_space = i;
        terminator = input;
        break;
    }

    sentence[i] = input;
}

if (terminator == 0)
{
    printf("Sentence needs a terminating character. (./?/!)\n\n");
    return 0;
}

printf("Reversal of sentence: ");
for (i = last_space; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (sentence[i] == ' ')
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j != last_space; j++)
        {
            putchar(sentence[j]);
        }
        last_space = i;
        putchar(sentence[i]);
    }
}
while (sentence[i] != '\0' && sentence[i] != ' ')
{
    putchar(sentence[i++]);
}
printf("%c\n\n", terminator);
for(int i=sizeof(pos)-1; i>0; i--){
    printf("%.*s", sentence[pos[i-1]], sentence[pos[i]]);
}
printf("%c\n\n", terminator);
return 1;
}
```

This keeps crashing because of the method at the bottom here:

```
printf("%c\n\n", terminator);
for(int i=sizeof(pos)-1; i>0; i--){
    printf("%.*s", sentence[pos[i-1]], sentence[pos[i]]);
}
printf("%c\n\n", terminator);
return 1;
}
```

Can someone help me fix this snippet of code for me so that both methods work when run? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I totally goofed up when writing but that is the question. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: C or C++ make your mind, and how is this question related to eclipse?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield re doesn't want to reverse the string but the individual works of the sentence.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Sorry, wrong link: Possible duplicate of [how can I reverse the words in a sentence...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277711/how-can-i-reverse-the-words-in-a-sentence-without-using-built-in-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array of size 1 is created by the line:

```
int pos[]={0};
```

And later you are accessing over the array's limit here:

```
if(input== ' '){
    pos[posc]=i;
    posc++;
}
```

The behaviour is undefined after that. The same mistake presents in the code you've mentioned due to sizeof returns the size in bytes, not just amount of elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simplest way to do it,
you just have to write a function who will write the last word of the sentence first, then the second and goes on ..

There you can find a working code

```
#include <unistd.h>

//This function print the last word or a space 
static int  print_last(const char *str, int len)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (len > 0 && str[len] == ' ')
        len--;
    while (i <= len && str[len - i] != ' ')
        i++;
    write(1, str + len - i + 1, i);
    while (len > 0 && str[len] == ' ')
        len--;
    if (i < len)
        write(1, " ", 1);
    return (len - i);
}

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
    int len = 0;
    if (ac == 2)
    {
        while (av[1][len])
            len++;
        len--;
        while (len > 0)
            len = print_last(av[1], len);
    }
    write(1, "\n", 1);
    return (0);
}
```

and there, once compiled (to compile --> `clang yourFileName.c`) , you can call the program like so 
`./youCompiledProgram 'the sentance you want to be inverted'`

[image: example]