# C - Reverse order of words in an array of Strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, reverse

I did this program to reverse the order of the words in the give string. (And it works)

i.e. Output: `sentence first the is This`

However I am stuck when it comes to adding another sentence to the array.
For example I need to have an array `{"This is the first sentence", "And this is the second"}` producing as output: `sentence first the is This , second the is this And`

```
int main() {

    char str[] = {"This is the first sentence"};
    int length = strlen(str);

    // Traverse string from end
    int i;
    for (i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {

    // putting the NULL character at the position of space characters for 
    next iteration.
        str[i] = '\0';

        // Start from next character
        printf("%s ", &(str[i]) + 1);
        }
}

    // printing the last word
    printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

I am new to C so its not surprising that I got stuck even if the solution is quite easy. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Try with two dimensional array.

Comment: Possible duplicate check answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871795/how-do-i-do-reverse-sentence-in-this-simple-way/48872091#48872091

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I do reverse sentence in this simple way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48871795/how-do-i-do-reverse-sentence-in-this-simple-way)

Comment: How can (one of) the most handled problem(s) within SO's C-tag still be such an issue? ;>

Comment: To be fair, the question here is _not_ how to reverse a string or array, and not even how to reverse the words in a sentence – the OP has already solved that problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the code to print the words of one string in reverse order, I would suggest making that a *function* which takes a single string as an argument, i.e.:

```
void print_words_reverse(char * const str) {
    // your current code here
}
```

Then you can call it separately for each string:

```
char strings[][30] = {
    "This is the first sentence",
    "And this is the second"
};
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(strings) / sizeof(*strings); ++i) {
    print_words_reverse(strings[i]);
}
```

Note that since you are modifying the string (by replacing spaces with NUL bytes), the argument needs to be modifiable, which means you are not allowed to call it (in standard C) with a pointer to a string literal, which means you can't simply use `const char *strings[] = { "first", "second" }`. You could get rid of the ugly constant length (here `30`) reserved for every string by making your code not modify the argument string. Or you could have a separate char array for each sentence and then use pointers to those (modifiable) strings.

Comment: You may also wish to print a newline after the last word.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can try with a two-dimensional array or use an array of pointers.

Secondly, in your approach, you lose the initial value of your string, I don't know how important it is.

This is my fast approach using arrray of pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void print_word(const char *str)
{
    for (int i = 0; str[i] && str[i] != ' '; i++)
        printf("%c", str[i]);
    putchar(' ');
}

int main(void)
{
    int len;
    const char *str[] = {"This is the first sentence",
                         "And this is second", NULL};

    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) { 
        for (len = strlen(str[i]); len >= 0; len--) {
            if (len == 0)
                print_word(&str[i][len]);
            else if (str[i][len] == ' ') 
                print_word(&str[i][len + 1]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    printf("Initial value of array of strings [%s | %s] \n", str[0], str[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

output is:

> sentence first the is This
>
> second is this And
>
> Initial value of array of strings [This is the first sentence | And this is second]

Comment: I would use `const char *str` to make it clear that the pointers are to non-modifiable strings. Also, I would advise against syntax like `if (len == 0 || …) len == 0 ? … : …` – rather make it a separate branch like `if (len == 0) { … } else if (str[i][len] == ' ') { … }`, or use `print(&str[i][len == 0 ? len : len + 1])`. (The latter might also tempt some people to use `print(&str[i][len + (len != 0)])` but I wouldn't go there, either.) Would also suggest naming `print` something more descriptive and less likely to collide.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using `memcpy` but without altering too much your code this seems to work

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 100

int main()
{
    char *str[] = {"This is the first", "And this is the second sentence"};
    const size_t NUM_STRING = sizeof(str)/sizeof(char*);
    /*%z used to print size_t variables*/
    printf("%zd strings found\n", NUM_STRING);
    int length[2];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<NUM_STRING; i++)
    {
        length[i] = strlen(str[i]);
    }
    printf("length initialized %d %d\n", length[0], length[1]);

    // Traverse string from end
    int j = 0;
    char temp[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
    printf("\n\n");
    for (j=0; j<NUM_STRING; j++)
    {
      /*Make sure the string respect the MAX_STRING_LENGTH limit*/
      if (strlen(str[j])>MAX_STRING_LENGTH)
      {
        printf("ERROR: string %d exceding max string length %d defined in constant "
        "MAX_STRING_LENGTH. Exiting from program.\n", j, MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
        exit(1);
      }
      //reset temporary string
      memset(temp, '\0', sizeof(temp));
      //printf("temp variable reinitialized\n");
      for (i = length[j] - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
        temp[i] = str[j][i];
        if (str[j][i] == ' ')
        {
          // putting the NULL character at the position of space characters for  next iteration.
          temp[i] = '\0';
          // Start from next character
          printf("%s ", &(temp[i]) + 1);
        }
      }

      // printing the last word
      printf("%s ", temp);
    }
    printf("\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using only `length[0]` where `length[j]` was probably intended. You should also check that `temp` is long enough (or use the C99 VLA `temp[length[j] + 1]`). And the `memset` to zero `temp` is unnecessary, and since you have it outside the loop body it doesn't even ensure the last word is correctly terminated beyond the first iteration – perhaps `temp[length[j]] = '\0'` inside the loop would suffice.

Comment: You are right about `length[j]`. I am assuming that being an exercise strings are those in the code or not more different than the others: you are right in general though. Why is `memset` unnecessary? The program might work anyway but in my opinion it is better to inzialize arrays to avoid undesired effects.

Comment: `memset` is unnecessary because initializing to zeroes right before populating is, well, unnecessary. And it caused the bug where you assume that it has zeroes, when that is only true for the first iteration of the outer loop. (The bug is harder to discover now, but it's still there.) And if you really want to be defensive and set it to zeroes (outside of the loop), the simpler syntax would be `char temp[100] = { 0 };`, which would also let the compiler decide how best to accomplish it.

Comment: **`memset` is unnecessary because initializing to zeroes right before populating is, well, unnecessary.**: the string I am populating the array with is actually (it must be) shorter then the elements of the array: If I do not `memset` elements after of the array whose indexes are bigger than the length of the string are uninitialized. You are right about `NUM_STRING` but please keep it in mind this is an exercise and not the main point of the answer. Your are right though about `MAX_STRING_COUNT` I was going to use it then I changed my mind.

Comment: In my opinion you are not right about the bug caused by `memset`: it was caused by `for (i = length[0] - 1; i >= 0; i--)`: changing this line to `for (i = length[j] - 1; i >= 0; i--)` seems to work

Comment: Anyway I tried to implement your suggestion in the code.

Comment: The `length[j]` did not fix the bug, but moving `memset` inside the loop did. If you move `memset` back outside the loop like it originally was, and use the strings `"foo", "2"` it still breaks. As for uninitialized elements, that is the exact bug! Your solution is to _every time_ zero _all_ elements, when the real problem is that there is _one_ missing zero. You could fix it simply by `temp[length[j]] = '\0'` instead of the `memset` – which could be achieved by using `for (i = length[j]; i >= 0; --i)` as the loop… So, by relying on "all zeroes" you hid the bug and missed the simple solution.

Comment: Yes `memset` outside was an error but I did not see the segmentation when running (maybe you were correct but it depends on the machine and its memory). I don't get your second point: are you saying memsetting everything to `0` is unnecessary since it is enough to just put the end-string char in the string? Apart from that the code should be ok now: isn't it? Anyway thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying memsetting everything to zero is unnecessary since it is enough to just put the one end-of-string zero in the string. _Writing_ to uninitialized memory is not a problem, reading is. The only thing in this code reading `temp` is `printf`, and it stops when it sees the terminator, so it doesn't matter if the rest is uninitialized or not. As for "segmentation", if you mean segmentation fault, your code never crashed with that because you had the `memset`. It _might_ have crashed without the `memset` at all, which would have been better since then you would have seen the problem!

Comment: **It might have crashed without the memset at all, which would have been better since then you would have seen the problem**: what problem? As far as I know segmentation is when you are accessing areas of memory you should not and as such information might be leaked or unwanted code executed or other problems so it is the first thing to avoid. Secondly setting the array to a known value I am avoiding unexpected behaviour if the code is modified or put as part of another program: it seems to me more robust.

Comment: Think of it in this way: C strings have a zero terminator. `printf` expects C strings, so the contract is that you must ensure whatever you pass to `printf` has a zero terminator. The problem in your code was that there are cases where you don't put the terminator. First your `memset` outside the loop hid the problem with those strings and I had to point it out. Your solution of moving it inside the loop solves it, but it is unclear to a reader that the `memset` is actually required for string termination. A simple `temp[length[j]] = '\0'` would make it obvious what it is for…

Comment: Ok so with the code as it is now it is not a problem, rather you are pointing out a question of clearness and clarity.

Comment: As for avoiding unexpected behaviour, I think you are doing the opposite here. If someone looks at the code and sees you do `memset` inside a loop where you immediately overwrite all (but one of) those zeroes, they might very well optimize your `memset` away (e.g., if they needed to do this for a million strings, it would be a performance issue), or put it behind some `#ifdef PRODUCTION`. Then it would stop working _in some cases_. During development it is much better for code to fail early than to just happen to work, and this is why we have tools like Valgrind.

Comment: During development I would argue it would even be better to `memset` to something _other_ than zero to make it fail more easily, which would be better to get the rest of the code fixed…